# 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault' in another window controller

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I have this mac application that uses `coredata`. It has an entity called `OfferedClasses`, one called `Pupils` and one called `Professors`.

The `classes` entity has a relationship to each of the other entities. It can have one `professor` and several `pupils`.

Each entity has a class representation expanding the `NSManagedObject` class.

I also have two windows. One is owned by `AppDelegate` and has a list of the `classes` entity with an option to create and other to delete the `classes`' rows.

The second window is owned by a class I call `PeopleManager`. I have two tabs there, one with a list of `professors` and one with a list of `pupils`. The same tools to add and remove the rows are available in this window.

While testing my application I came to a weird behaviour triggered by this sequence of actions:

1. Open both windows (`app delegate` to manage classes and `people` to manage people);
2. Create a new `class` row (pupils and professor are nil at this point);
3. Delete the new `class` row (suppose it is wrong);
4. Move to the `people manager`;
5. Remove one random `professor` row.

The application crashes with the following error:

```
2013-10-04 09:37:40.286 Application[415:903] Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing: CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x10188f020 <x-coredata://89D3EA2E-DF58-4995-8FEA-BD1D237F1B28/OfferedClasses/p45>' with userInfo {
    NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey =     (
        "<OfferedClassesEntityModel: 0x10188a260> (entity: OfferedClasses; id: 0x10188f020 <x-coredata://89D3EA2E-DF58-4995-8FEA-BD1D237F1B28/OfferedClasses/p45> ; data: <fault>)"
    );
}
```

Now, while searching the Internet (I searched stackoverflow too) for this message I came across the concept that my `managed object context` is somehow messed up. However, the majority of the examples seem to be in an application with multiple threads and both object contexts are not synchronised. They often have `grand central dispatch` issues, etc. Mine is a simple window controller and I don't try to use different object contexts here. I'll try to summarise:

In my AppDelegate I have the following properties:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator * persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel * managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext;
```

... and I implement manually the following methods:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel;
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator;
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;
```

To open the `people manager` window I use this code:

```
- (IBAction)showPeopleWindow:(id)sender {
    //Gets the Managed Object Context:
    NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (!peopleWindowController) {
        peopleWindowController = [
            [PeopleWindowController alloc]
                initWithManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext
        ];
    }
    [peopleWindowController showWindow:self];
}
```

The `professors` list is handled with bindings: in the interface builder I have an `array controller` for professors and in the `attributes inspector` I use `mode` set to `Entity Name` and `Entity Name` set to `Professors` with `Prepares Content` and `Editable` ticked.

In the `Bindings Inspector` I have `Managed Object Context` set to `File's Owner` and `Model Key Path` set to `managedObjectContext`.

The bug doesn't happen with the `Pupils` entity and it only happens when I delete a row of `OfferedClasses`.

The class `OfferedClassesEntityModel` mentioned in the error is one of the `NSManagedObject` classes. It has the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class RelationshipClassesPupilsEntityModel, ProfessorEntityModel, PupilEntityModel;
@interface OfferedClassesEntityModel : NSManagedObject
//(...)
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet * pupils;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ProfessorEntityModel * professor;
//(...)
@interface OfferedClassesEntityModel (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addPupilsObject:(RelationshipClassesPupilsEntityModel *)value;
- (void)removePupilsObject:(RelationshipClassesPupilsEntityModel *)value;
- (void)addPupils:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePupils:(NSSet *)values;
//(...)
@end
```

All properties are implemented with `@dynamic`.

This is the `PeopleWindowController` init method:

```
- (id)initWithManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)theManagedObjectContext {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"PeopleWindow"];
    if (self) {
        managedObjectContext = theManagedObjectContext;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Please help, I have no idea where is the issue.

I tried this: [How do we prevent "CoreData could not fulfill a fault"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969034/how-do-we-prevent-coredata-could-not-fulfill-a-fault)

The observer works fine, but any actions to update the MOC won't work.

One more thing: it only crashes with newly created `classes`. Meaning that if I saved a `class` row in a previous execution, it works fine.

Also: When a `class` row is created, it has no relationship set. It's `professor` is null!

Thanks!

Comment: professor's relationship is already set to nullify. Pupils is fine, it uses cascade

Answer (score 0):

If it isnt a threading issue / multicontext issue, then it is due to a wrong delete rule set on a relationship I'd say.

the pupil still has a relation to the deleted objects.

Set it to nullify

Comment: Hi Daij-Djan, professor's relationship is already set to nullify. Pupils is fine, it uses cascade.